# React Tutorial's Webpack Hot Reload not working out of box

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am following a great new React tutorial on YouTube located here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iAG6h9ff5s&feature=youtu.be

Everything he is doing is working as he progresses through the tutorial and
he has made his code available on his repo located here:
https://github.com/learncodeacademy/react-js-tutorials

**PROBLEM:**
I clone his repo, cd into the directory, run "npm install" then "npm run dev" and get no hot reload.

Navigating to localhost shows the correct page, all of the routing works, but making any change does not result in a refresh.
Killing the server and restarting it shows changes made.

I am missing something and don't know what, any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: On a possible related note: running "webpack" does create the bundle but running "webpack --watch" doesn't rebundle and refresh on change either...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't miss anything: there isn't any hot-reload configured. Take a look at his webpack configurations.

Edit: There is no react-hot-loader (my bad). Remove `client.min.js` for the time being, let it be served by `webpack-dev-server`.

Comment: I am learning this now so my knowledge is very limited. What I know is that on his screen, his page is reloading as it should. And in the tutorial I believe he only makes reference to this line in his package.json.
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot"
  }

Comment: Am I understanding that adding "--inline --hot" is not sufficient and he may have accidentally left out a step or assumed we may have something already configured?

Comment: @Stefan I've made an edit to my answer. I think this is because of `client.min.js` being present on your hard drive (so it will be served before the `webpack-dev-server`), maybe find an other boilertplate that suits more your needs ?

Comment: Well I am very much a beginner to this, not only React but Node, Webpack, and pretty much everything that comes with it. His video tutorials are hands down the most clear I have come across and take me to the perfect jumping off point for beginning to really try and learn this. 
If it is at all possible I would really like to get his example up and running.